# Java web app authentication framework similar to django-auth

Tags: java, authentication

Looking for an authentication and authorization solution for Java web application (servlet based). Similar to [django-auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/), featuring;

- support for different backends (SQL, LDAP)
- user administration interface
- roles based permissions
- user registration and password reset workflows
- user profile interface
- REST APIs security support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JHipster](http://jhipster.tech/) seems to be the closest framework. It allows you to integrate several technologies (e.g: Spring Boot + Angular, React, Vue). Also it is extensible using *modules and blueprints*.

User management was introduced into [generator-jhipster](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster) since [this MR](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/1930)